# Riak - Riak server TCP port wont stay open on Mac OSX. Keeps disconnecting {:tcp_closed, #Port<x.x.x.x>}

Tags: erlang, elixir, riak

I'm new to Riak, and just trying to learn more and play around with it. I have tried installing both via Brew and tar.gz from the Riak site.

The install goes fine, and the server starts with `riak start` / `bin/riak start`, respectively. It does spit out a warning about ulimit

```
$ bin/riak start
!!!!
!!!! WARNING: ulimit -n is 256; 65536 is the recommended minimum.
!!!!
```

When I connect in ERTS (via elixir here). It works, but then the Riak server dies. It's not always immediately, so I dont think making the connection is what's killing it, because sometimes it will die before the connection.

```
iex(2)> {:ok, pid} = :riakc_pb_socket.start_link('127.0.0.1', 8087)
{:ok, #PID<0.126.0>}
** (EXIT from #PID<0.120.0>) :disconnected

Interactive Elixir (1.3.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> 
00:29:21.924 [error] GenServer #PID<0.126.0> terminating
** (stop) :disconnected
Last message: {:tcp_closed, #Port<0.3653>}
State: {:state, '127.0.0.1', 8087, false, false, :undefined, false, :gen_tcp, :undefined, {[], []}, 1, [], :infinity, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, [], 100}
```

Any reason that this is happening?

Comment: Peter, your ulimit is really low. I don't know if that is causing your problem but I would increase the open files limit and try again: http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/using/performance/open-files-limit/#mac-os-x

Comment: Do you see anything in the log files of Riak (specially crash.log)? If you installed via brew, it should be somewhere under /usr/local/var/log/riak/